# create shortcuts for .exe files to open in dosbox

Tags: dos, dosbox

I recently downloaded some old dos games and I am running them using dosbox, is there a way to open these .exe files other than going to the path of each game's directory and run the .exe ? creating shortcut or something ?

Answer (score 1):

Copying from the official [DOSBox page](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/DOSBoxShortcuts):

- Create a new shortcut to the DOSBox .exe file, or copy the one created when you installed DOSBox.
- Edit the properties of the shortcut.
- At the end of the "Target" line, add, in quotes, the full path of the main game executable that you wish to launch.

  - For example, if "The Settlers 2" was installed into the folder C:\Games\Settlers 2\, and DosBox is installed at it's default location, the target box would contain:
  - "C:\Program Files\DOSBox-0.72\dosbox.exe" -conf "C:\Program Files\DOSBox-0.72\dosbox.conf" "C:\Games\Settlers 2\S2.exe"

Answer (score 0):

You could create a batch file that you'd run after you start DOSBox.  Something simple like:

```
cd C:\mygamedir
mygame.exe
```

Alternately, it looks like there are some [front-ends to DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/DOSBoxFrontends) that you might find useful.